# Assigned To not set on TFS 2012 to Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I've run multiple migrations for different projects using the Ops Hub Tool, which have all run without any errors but not one of them sets the "Assigned To" field on Work Items. Is there some configuration trick in order to get the "Assigned To" to be set in Visual Studio Online?

Comment: We tried with different templates of TFS but we are not able to reproduce this issue. Can you please tell us more details on this. 
1.       WorkItem type/all types on which you are facing this issue for setting user details?
2.       Template type for which you encountered this issue?
3.       Any other user fields which are not set correctly on VSO side after migration?
Kindly send us log files in zip from location <install location> :\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs  on ovsmu@opshub.com email address.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look into this. Please my see my answer below, perhaps there is a modification you can make to handle the scenario I encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The projects had previously been migrated from TFS 2008 to TFS 2012 and at that time the User Accounts were recreated. For various reasons errors were encountered when trying to align the identities so the User Accounts have an identical display name but were for identities that were not valid. The TFS Work Items will display the  invalid user in the Assigned To field but you wouldn't be able to edit and save the work item until you selected a valid user.

So for the work items that were still set to the invalid identities (all the historic tasks prior to the initial migration) the Assigned To field is not being set. We had a couple of projects that had not been modified since then (and of course I started with those projects) thus it appeared that Assigned To was not being populated at all. I figured out what the problem was when I moved onto a project with more recent activity.